# How to write a regex that finds titles that end with question marks and all subsequent text?

Tags: java, json, regex

I have a document where the titles of a section are all questions. I need to write a regular expression to capture all of the titles plus the text in the sections that follow them and output to a json file.

**Example text:**

```
Is running healthy?

Sentence 1. Sentence 2. Sentence 3.

What leads to coughing?

Sentence 1. Sentence 2. Sentence 3.

What are the treatments?

Sentence 1. Sentence 2. Sentence 3.
```

**I want the output to look like this:**

```
{Title: Is running healthy?,
Text: Sentence 1. Sentence 2. Sentence 3.}

{Title: What leads to coughing?,
Text: Sentence 1. Sentence 2. Sentence 3.}

{Title: What are the treatments?,
Text: Sentence 1. Sentence 2. Sentence 3.}
```

Currently I'm using this regular expression to find and group all of the first lines that end with question marks and the texts that follows:

`(?m)([^.?!]+\\?)\\n(.*?)\\n(?=([^.?!]+\\?)|.*$)`

However it only outputs the first question and like half of the following paragraph.

So the output with this expression is:

```
{Title: Is running healthy?,
Text: Sentence 1.}
```

I need it to capture every title question and all of the subsequent text.

Any help?

Comment: Can you please add example text?

Comment: @Tamas Rev. I added the example text from the document I'm processing

Comment: Can the non-question sentences be separated by line breaks too?

Comment: @Mena Yes they can, but they all need to be grouped into one text field for my json file.

Comment: Please turn your code into an MCVE so that people can easily compile and run it for themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To capture all sentences up to the next question match any text after a question in non-greedy fashion (`(.*)?`) followed by a question or end of text (`(?=^(.*?)\?$|\Z)`). The latter should be matched using positive look-behind since it's a zero-length assertion.

```
(?ms)(^[^.?!]+\?)(.*?)(?=^(.*?)\?$|\Z)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/yEOtAa/1

Comment: Thank you so much!! This fixed it!